# How to pass a chart from MPAndroidChart from one activity to another?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, mpandroidchart

The charts that I create using the MPAndroidChart library are populated using data that comes from a web service which takes a little time. Hence in this time I wish to show a Splashscreen so the network calls can be made in the back ground, a chart will be formed and then passed to the MainActivity where it is to be shown.
For this I wish to pass two BarChart and a RadarChart object from the Splachscreen activity to the MainActivity.

So how can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the data not the graph. You can pass the data as so:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("new_variable_name","value");
startActivity(i);
```

and get it it new activity this way:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
}
```

You might have to pass the data as parcelable or serializable depending on what kind of data you have.

Then you can draw the graph on the new activity with the data you passed.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion your overall design approach needs a little refinement.

First, I recommend you avoid using a splash Activity to 'contain' the network operations. From a user experience perspective this could be poor, because the splash screen could be in view for an indeterminate amount of time from one use to the next. If the splash screen stays for more than, say, two seconds, then the application might appear to have become unresponsive. If you insist on doing it this way, I recommend that the splash screen at least contains dynamic status information to inform the user what's going on.

Next, be sure to perform your networking operation on a dedicated Thread, *not* on the main UI thread.

For the `MainActivity` to reference the fetched data, I suggest you look at the singleton pattern to hold it in memory. That is, either use a dedicated singleton object, or hold it in a subclass of `Application`. This way, the networking operation sets the data in that singleton, and the `MainActivity` obtains it from the singleton. Optionally, when you create the `Intent` for the `MainActivity`, the `Bundle` could perhaps contain a String which acts as a key to obtain the data. The reason I'm suggesting this strategy is because I am assuming that there might be a large amount of data involved. If on the other hand it's a very small amount of data, perhaps you might be able to get away with putting the data itself into the `Bundle`, perhaps as JSON in a String, or something.

Do keep in mind that if the application goes to the background and is then later resumed, you might be in a situation where your Activity stack is resumed, but all of your application's 'global' state is gone. This means that your `MainActivity` would be resumed, but the data you expected to be in your singleton class isn't there any more. Your `MainActivity` should have the means to cope with this, perhaps by setting off a fresh network request.